# How to estimate the average time complexity of greatest common divisor?

Tags: time-complexity, number-theory, average-case

As we know, the time complexity of $\gcd(x,y)$ is $O(\log \min(x,y))$ by using Euclidean algorithm. Now we fix a constant $n$ and consider the average time complexity of $\gcd(x,n)$.

Formally, let $f(x)$ be the number of divisions when calculating $\gcd(x,n)$. How to give a bound of $\frac 1 n \sum_{x=1}^n f(x)$?

I don't konw whether it is strictly $o(\log n)$ or $\Theta(\log n)$. How to prove the bound?

I list some of $n$ and the coresponding value here.

$n$ ; $\frac 1 n \sum_{x=1}^n f(x)$
1000;6.42;
10000;8.34;
100000;10.26;
1000000;12.20;
10000000;14.13;
100000000;16.07;

Comment: Are you interested in the _cost_ of the Euclidian algorithm, or in the _complexity_ of the problem?

Comment: Note that the averaging sum you give is _not_ what we commonly call "average case". The latter averages about all inputs of the same size (typically $n$) while your sum averages over all numbers up to value (!) $n$, i.e. including all smaller inputs as well.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Yes, I just want to fix a variable and sum over the other. I have written a program to check the value, as listed above.

Comment: do you see the pattern $10^x$ gives $\approx 2 x$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Average

Answer (score 1):

If you start wit a pair (a, b), a>=b, one step goes to (b,a’) with a’ < a/2. This gives an easy upper bound for the number is steps. You can analyse two steps from (a, b) to (a’, b,’) and get a slightly better upper bound.

For a lower bound for the highest number of steps, if a and b are the n-th an (n-1)-st Fibonacci number, then you will go through pairs of Fibonacci numbers and take n steps.

Answer (score 0):

Since $n\geq x$ in your sum, $O(\log\min(x,n))$ simplifies to $O(\log x)$. Being very careless with constants here, but $$\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{x=1}^n f(x)=\frac{1}{n}\left(n\cdot O(\log n)\right)=O(\log n)$$

I'm not sure what this is calculating though; average runtime of all input sizes less than $n$?

Comment: Yes, $O(\log n)$ is obvious, but I am curious about the lower bound.

Comment: Looking at your calculations, it seems that the values do correspond to about $2\log n$. So without a thorough analysis (just looking at the calculations), I would say it is $\Theta(\log n)$.

Comment: @zbh2047:  you didn't ask a lower bound, did you ? And from a given $O$ bound, you can't derive a lower bound.